# Sending organisation custom tokens to individual

Tags: wordpress, civimail, custom-fields, relationships, tokens

I want to use CiviMail to bulk mail key individual contacts from member organisations and want to include tokens in their email to remind them of the information we currently hold on their organisation, namely, the name and email address of the key contact and the invoice contact, and also some custom fields saved against their organisation.  I've created draft text with the following tokens but when I send a test email, the tokens are just showing as blank.  I suspect it's because the email is sent to individuals but the tokens relate to their organisational information rather than their personal information.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  We're using Wordpress.

Main contact is: {relationships.first_name_15_b_a} {relationships.last_name_15_b_a}

Email: {relationships.email_15_b_a}

Invoice contact is: {relationships.first_name_16_b_a} {relationships.last_name_16_b_a}

Email: {relationships.email_16_b_a}

Number of homes = {contact.custom_2}

Number of tenants = {contact.custom_3}

Number of staff = {contact.custom_4}

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with the [reltoken](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.reltoken) extension.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that Jon - did not know that extension yet

Comment: Thank you!  Will mention this extension to our developers

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange Helen!

I am not aware of any core function that can do what you want. With a little bit of coding or manual work (import/export) you could try an approach like this:

1. Create custom fields for the individuals that can hold organisation
   information
2. Create a skript or use an extension like [SQL-Tasks](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sql-tasks-extension-configurable-recurring-tasks) or [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) that copies all relevant organisation information to the individual's custom fields in regular intervals or on demand. That however most likely requires coding and/or SQL-knowledge.
3. Use the tokens for the individual custom fields when sending out the email.

If you cannot / do not want to code or use the extensions mentioned you could try and export the organisation information and re-import it into the custom fields.

Make sure to test properly whichever approach you take :)

Comment: Thanks - that's really useful to know the core functions don't do that, as our CRM developer hadn't identified there would be any issue when they set it up.  Will have a think about the best approach to take now - really appreciate you sharing the different options.